# How to parse xml data with attribute values in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml-parsing

I have a xml data like below:

```
<toplevel>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna like a prayer"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna like a virgin"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna vogue"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna la isla bonita"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna frozen"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna holiday"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna music"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna gimme all your love"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
<CompleteSuggestion>
<suggestion data="madonna celebration"/>
</CompleteSuggestion>
</toplevel>
```

I am parsing this by using a XMLParser class below:

```
 public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             Log.e("in element","element");
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 Log.e("in child","child nodes");
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                       Log.e("in for","for loop");
                     child = elem.getFirstChild();
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         Log.e("in if condition","if cond");
                         return elem.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

Here is my Activity code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML

    Log.e("string xml","hello"+xml);
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

    NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        Log.e("no. of items",""+i);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

        map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

        Log.e("names","hi"+parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

        menuItems.add(map);
    }
```

I observed that my  getElementValue( Node elem ) in XmLParser is always returning empty String. I think I need to change this method. I tried by changing some of the statements but didn't find any solution.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html. use `XmlPullParser`.

Comment: I likes to know why I am getting this error, how to resolve this.

Comment: if you are using xml pullparser then you can look at the docs has an example also.

Comment: Please check this answer It may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/41377333/1621789